# Does GNU grep's -o option ignore zero-length matches?

Tags: text-processing, grep, pcre

I found an answer on another site that was suggesting `grep -oP '^\w+|$`. I pointed out that the `|$` is pointless in PCRE, since it just means "OR end of line" and will therefore always be true for regular lines. However, I can't exactly figure out what it does in GNU `grep` PCREs when combined with `-o`. Consider the following:

```
$ printf 'ab\na\nc\n\n' | perl -ne 'print if /ab|$/'
ab
a
c

$
```

(I am including the second prompt (`$`) character to show that the empty line is included in the results).

As expected, in Perl, that will match every line. Either because it contains an `ab` or because the `$` matches the end of the line. GNU `grep` behaves the same way without the `-o` flag:

```
$ printf 'ab\na\nc\n\n' | grep -P 'ab|$'
ab
a
c

$
```

However, `-o` changes the behavior:

```
$ printf 'ab\na\nc\n\n' | grep -oP 'ab|$'
ab
$
```

This is the same as simply grepping for `ab`. The second part, the "OR end of line" seems to be ignored. It does work as expected without the `-o` flag:

What's going on? Does -`o` ignore 0-length matches? Is that a bug or is it expected?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My GNU grep man page says the following:

> -o, --only-matching
>
> > Print only the matched (**non-empty**) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

emphasis is mine

I'm guessing it considers the end of line match to be an "empty match"

Answer (score 0):

#### Sides of an OR

*The second part, the "OR end of line" seems to be ignored.*

No, it isn't, if we change the match slightly:

```
$ printf 'ab\na\n\nc\n' | grep -oP 'ab|.$'
ab
a
c
```

Both parts of the *OR* are explicitly matched.

#### Empty match

What **is** ignored are "empty" matches (the resulting string has zero length):

```
$ printf '%s\n' ab " " a "" c | grep -oP '^.*$'
ab

a
c
```

It is documented (in GNU grep) `LESS=+'/^ *-o,' man grep` (emphasis mine):

> -o, --only-matching
>   
>       `Print only the matched (`**non-empty**`) parts of a matching line,
>       with each such part on a separate output line.`